# Make a button asynchronous in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I have to put this two "on tap" functions in only one button. The thing is that I only can execute the `Navigator.push` after `saveQuestionModel()` and `loadQuestions()` have been already executed.

```
 onTap: () {
    saveQuestionModel(_key, snapshot.data);
    loadQuestions(_key);
 },

 onTap: () {
    Navigator.push(
     context,
     MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => QuizScreen(
           code: _key,
           index: _currentIndex,
        ),
     ),
  );
```

I tried like this but did not work

```
 onTap: () async {
    saveQuestionModel(_key, snapshot.data);
    loadQuestions(_key);
    await Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
         builder: (context) => QuizScreen(
           code: _key,
           index: _currentIndex,
         ),
      ),
    );
  },
```

Is there a way of doing that without using two separated buttons?

Comment: how do you have two onTap on single button?

Comment: I dont, i have 2 different buttons

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate method that will hold all your methods and use `await` before future methods.

```dart
void myFun() async{
   
   await myFutureLoad();   
   // include others
   ....

}
```

And use this `myFun` on widget `onTap`

```dart
onTap: myFun,
```

For your case, you can do

```dart
 onTap: () async{
    await saveQuestionModel(_key, snapshot.data);
    await loadQuestions(_key);
     Navigator.push(
     context,
     MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => QuizScreen(
           code: _key,
           index: _currentIndex,
        ),
     ),
  );
 },
```

More about [dart async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Comment: I cant do this because I'm inside a futurebuilder and need the snapshot to load the question

Comment: Can you update your question, For futureBuilder case, we define our widgets(data-related) on `snapshot.hasData` cases, after the loading state.

Comment: I dont understand. What do you want me to show on the question?

Comment: The way you've implemented inside futureBuilder.  Can you try putting `await` before 1st two methods  and creating separate method if needed as shown in this post?

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked now, I had to change the fuction type of loadQuestion and save from void to Future<void> and add the awaits inside the onTap but it works niw. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can find more on https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Do you have an answer for https://stackoverflow.com/q/72775512/12349734 ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it should be

```
onTap:()async{
  await saveQuestionModel();
  await loadQuestions();
  
  Navigator.push(...)
}
```

Here basically it waits for both the functions to end executing before pushing the next page using `Navigator.push()`